# Align horizontally 3 elements over 3 divs

Tags: alignment, flexbox

I have 3 articles in a row that have each a title, a description and a link list. The amount of content is always different, heights of the 3 elements are unknown. I am trying to align the corresponding ones horizontally to each other using flexbox. Anyone can help? 
Here's an example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Horizontal Alignment</title>
    <style type="text/css">

        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0; }

        li {
            list-style: none; }

        * {
            box-sizing: border-box; }

        .item-container {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap; }

        .item {
            width: 33.3%;
            border: 1px dashed black;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column; }

        .item-title {
            background: red;
            flex: 1 0 auto; }

        .item-description {
            background: orange; }

        .item-links {
            background: yellow; }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="item-container">
        <div class="item">
            <h2 class="item-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
            <p class="item-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. </p>
            <ul class="item-links">
                <li>Link A</li>
                <li>Link B</li>
                <li>Link C</li>
                <li>Link D</li>
                <li>Link E</li>
                <li>Link F</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h2 class="item-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. </h2>
            <p class="item-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
            <ul class="item-links">
                <li>Link A</li>
                <li>Link B</li>
                <li>Link C</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h2 class="item-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
            <p class="item-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. </p>
            <ul class="item-links">
                <li>Link A</li>
                <li>Link B</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

[Copepen](http://codepen.io/tinusmile/pen/ggKXXx)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By making a minor change in your markup, removing the `<div class="item">` wrapper, you can do like this.

Here I used the `order` property to re-order/group the `item-title`, `item-description`, and `item-links` in a top, middle and bottom block, and as such they will have equal heights on each row.

*Updated based on a comment, with a media query*

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.item-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.item-container > * {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
.item-title {
  background: red;
}
.item-description {
  background: orange;
}
.item-links {
  background: yellow;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {

  .item-container > * {
    width: 33.3%;
  }

  .item-container > h2 {
    order: 1;
  }
  .item-container > p {
    order: 2;
  }
  .item-container > ul {
    order: 3;
  }

}
```

```html
<section class="item-container">

  <h2 class="item-title">1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
  <p class="item-description">1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
  <ul class="item-links">
    <li>1 Link A</li>
    <li>Link B</li>
    <li>Link C</li>
    <li>Link D</li>
    <li>Link E</li>
    <li>Link F</li>
  </ul>
  
  <h2 class="item-title">2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. </h2>
  <p class="item-description">2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
  <ul class="item-links">
    <li>2 Link A</li>
    <li>Link B</li>
    <li>Link C</li>
  </ul>

  <h2 class="item-title">3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
  <p class="item-description">3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
  <ul class="item-links">
    <li>3 Link A</li>
    <li>Link B</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Cool, works as described. But: as each former .item is an article for itself the 3 elements inside need to belong together in a one column layout. Any suggestion? That's why I was trying with a wrapper element.

Comment: @tinusmile But they are in 1 column each, I updated my answer and added number 1-3 in each element so you can clearly see that

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood my answer. For this layout with 3 columns in a row it's fine. But in small screens articles will have 100% width and will be aligned vertically... That's why it would be better to have a wrapper around each article, right? What do you think?

Comment: @tinusmile No, you can't do what you want with a wrapper, I will update my answer in a few minutes

Comment: @tinusmile Updated ... choose "Full page" and resize browser window and you'll see how it works

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! You helped me a lot, I was really fixed on a wrapper solution...

Comment: @tinusmile I see that you haven't accepted any of the answer given to your questions. You are suppose to, so future users can see which answer solved the question best, so please go over them and do that ... that is one of the rewards we get for putting in our free time to help the one's that seeks an answer

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to be wrong, I didn't know how to do. I marked your answer, ok so?

Comment: @tinusmile That's fine, understand you don't want that ... and thanks