# Horizontal align text below flex-items

Tags: flexbox, text-alignment

Image captions are aligned bottom by flexbox within a gallery where images have different heights. How can I achieve that first lines of text (titles) are aligned horizontally?

```
<style type="text/css">

    * {
        box-sizing: border-box; }

    .flex-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap; }

    .flex-item {
        width: 50%;
        padding: 20px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column; } 

    .flex-item img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto; }

    .flex-image {
        flex: 1 0 auto; }

</style>
```

```
<div class="flex-container">

    <div class="flex-item">
        <div class="flex-image">
            <img src="img-1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <p>title</p>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-item">
        <div class="flex-image">
            <img src="img-2.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <p>title<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Please check my codepen: https://codepen.io/tinusmile/pen/MoeORG

Many thanks!

Comment: I just updated my answer with a second option, linked to my answer in your previous question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the existing markup, where the images can have different heights, you need to do something like this, where you give the `p` a height.

As an element's overflow defaults to `visible`, it will flow out of its boundaries, so I recommend to set the height so it can accommodate 2-3 lines of text.

On smaller screens you might need to add a `@media` query to adjust that height, as if the text is very long it might overflow any element below itself.

```
.flex-item p {
    height: 50px; }
```

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/weWpLx)

---

Note, using `min-height` instead would solve the *might overflow any element below itself* issue, though it will make the first line to not align horizontally if the value does not accommodate all the possible amount of lines.

---

Another option is to remove the `flex-item` wrapper and use Flexbox's `order` property, as I suggested in a previous question of yours, [align-horizontally-3-elements-over-3-divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42056054/align-horizontally-3-elements-over-3-divs/42056180#42056180)

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. The order option wasn't a proper solution here, I tried it before I posted my question.